# anaconda and conda terminal closes immediately

Tags: python, anaconda

I've recently re-installed anaconda(a python distribution) to update it. Both the conda terminal and anaconda immediately close just after opening.

Before the re-installation it did not work either. (unrelated: I need conda terminal to work because I'll install nmap and also create a virtual environment and then install tensorflow there.)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get through by opening anaconda terminal & then writing 'conda'. This have opened me conda and I made my way.